# Shiny app in Docker - connect port to default app directory

Tags: r, docker, shiny

I have a Shiny app running in a docker container and all seems to work fine.  When I start the Docker container and bind port 3838 to external port 3838, I can go to localhost:3838 and see the Shiny default screen.  To get to my app, I need to got to localhost:3838/MyApp.

Is there a way to run MyApp by default so that I don't have to include the /MyApp suffix but only use localhost:3838?

Comment: Are you using shiny-server? In general it's possible: [Here](https://www.shinyproxy.io/documentation/deploying-apps/) you can find an example.

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks!  I'll give this a try.